# How to set selected, unselected header title color in RowHeaderPresenter

Tags: android, leanback

I am using BrowseFragment from leanback library. I have extended RowHeaderPresenter to apply custom font. For customizing I followed sample application mentioned at [link](https://corochann.com/browsefragment-header-customization-android-tv-application-hands-on-tutorial-17-697.html). However, after making it custom, it stopped setting selected/unselected color of headers. I want it to have colors like "Library", "Continue watching", etc.

[image]

Right now, all items appear having same color as shown in tutorial link. I am looking some way to get selected position in RowHeaderPresenter.onBindViewHolder() so that I can set appropriate color.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `styles.xml` file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Leanback">
        <item name="sectionHeaderStyle">@style/MySectionHeaderStyle</item>
        <item name="rowHeaderStyle">@style/MyRowHeaderStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MySectionHeaderStyle" parent="Widget.Leanback.Row.Header">
        <item name="android:textColor">#90FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">14dp</item>
        <item name="android:textAlignment">center</item>
        <item name="android:background">#80000000</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">bottom</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyRowHeaderStyle" parent="Widget.Leanback.Header.Section">
        <item name="android:textColor">#DDFFFFFF</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">18dp</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```